# Having difficulty writing a script to sort words

Tags: bash, sorting

I am dealing with sorting words in Bash according to a given argument. I am given either argument `-r`, `-a` , `-v` or `-h` and according to it there are options to sort the words, as you can see at my "help".

Somehow, if I pass the argument `-r` it creates an error. I really don't understand what I am doing wrong, as `if[["$arg"=="-a"]]` works, but I have to use case somehow.

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Natalie Zubkova , zubkonat
# zubkonat@cvut.fel.cz , LS

#help
help="This script will calculate occurances of words in a given file, and it will sort them according to the given argument in following order> \n
without parametre = increasing order according to a number of occurance\n
-r    =  decreasing order according to a number of occurance\n
-a    =  in alphabetical increasing order\n
-a -r =  in alphabetical decreasing order\n
There are also special cases of the given parametre, when the script is not sorting but:\n

-h    = for obtaining help  \n
-v    = for obtaining a number of this task "

# this function will divide a given chain into a words, so we can start calculating the occurances, we also convert all the capital letters to the small ones by - tr

a=0;
r=0;
EXT=0;
if [ "$1" == "-h" ]; then
    echo $help
    exit 0
fi
if [ "$2" == "-h" ]; then
    echo $help
    exit 0
fi
if [ "$1" == "-v" ]; then
    echo "5"
    exit 0
fi
if [ "$2" == "-v" ]; then
    echo "5"
    exit 0
fi

function swap {
    while read x y; do
         echo "$y" "$x";
    done
}

function clearAll {
    sed -e 's/[^a-z]/\n/gI' | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' | sort | uniq -c |awk '{i++; if(i!=1) print $2" "$1}' #swap
}

for arg do
case "$arg" in
      "-a")
       a=1
       ;;
    "-r")
       r=1
       ;;
    "-v")
      echo "5"      #number of task is 5
      exit 0        
         ;;
    "-h")
     echo $help
     exit 0
     ;;
    "-?")
     echo "invalid parametre, please display a help using argument h"
     exit 0
     ;;
   esac
done
#Sort according to parametres -a and -r
function sortWords {       
        if [[ a -eq 1 ]]; then
           if [[ r -eq 0 ]]; then
           clearAll | sort -nk1
        fi  
              fi

              if [[ a -eq 1 ]]; then
        if [[ r -eq 1 ]]; then
            clearAll | sort -nk1 -r
        fi
           fi


        if [[ r -eq 1 ]]; then
            if [[ a -eq 0 ]]; then
           clearAll | sort -nk2 -r
        fi
           fi

        if [[ a -eq 0 ]]; then
            if [[ r -eq 0 ]]; then
            clearAll | sort -nk2
        fi 
    fi
}
#code is from Stackoverflow.com
 function cat-all {
    while IFS= read -r file
    do
        if [[ ! -z "$file" ]]; then
            cat "$file"
        fi
    done
 }
#histogram
hist=""
for arg do
    if [[ ! -e "$arg" ]]; then
               EXT=1;
        echo "A FILE DOESNT EXIST" >&2
        continue;
        elif [[ ! -f "$arg" ]]; then
               EXT=1;
        echo "A FILE DOESNT EXIST" >&2
        continue;
       elif [[ ! -r "$arg" ]]; then
                EXT=1;
        echo "A FILE DOESNT EXIST" >&2
       continue;
        fi
done
for arg do
    hist="$hist""$arg""\n"
done

echo -e "$hist" | cat-all | sortWords
exit $EXT;
```

Here is what our upload system which does some test to see if our program works says:

```
Test #6

> b5.sh  -r ./easy.txt

ERROR: script output is wrong:

--- expected output
+++ script stdout
@@ --- line 1 (167 lines) ; +++ no lines @@
-the 89
-steam 46
-a 39
-of 37
-to 35
...

script written 484 lines, while 484 lines are expected

script error output:

A FILE DOESNT EXIST
cat: invalid option -- 'r'
Try `cat --help' for more information.

script exit value: 1

ERROR: Interrupted due to failed test
```

If anyone could help me I would really appreciate it.

Comment: sorry, thats not a mistake i am looking for. That was just misclick here.

Comment: The cat error is because you are passing the argument `-r` to `cat-all` via `$hist` and then subsequently calling cat on everything passed to the function.

Comment: @JonnyHenly the file `-r` almost certainly doesn't exist.

Comment: @123 : ) just noticed it loops over `arg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to move the parameter index position with `shift`:

```
"-r")
   r=1
   shift
   ;;
```

`shift` above moves to the next command line arg: `./easy.txt` in your case.
Without it, `read -r file` will read `-r` instead of the file name.

Comment: That was exactly it. Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: I'm glad it's working. Don't forget to accept the answer if it's what you were looking for.